# How can I authenticate a user session in Core PHP (on each page) and restrict the user to reload the page or go back

Tags: php, html

I have created a page with login and logout facility in core PHP. When I login, the system starts a session and takes me to a new page where a unique key is passed in the URL which is nothing but the Primary Key of that particular user. But, when this key is changes, the user account is also changed easily without any authentication.

For example: If user A log in to the system with its own credentials, he is successfully logged in. Let's say his primary key is 2.

Thus he is taken to the following URL: `www.example.com/dashboard.php?id=2` Now, let's say that there is a user B with primary key 4 and if the user A manually changes the key the URL `www.example.com/dashboard.php?id=2` to `www.example.com/dashboard.php?id=4`, the session changes to user B. Thus, authenticity is not maintained.

The system should be like if the key in URL is changes manually, or page is force reloaded or back button is pressed, then the session needs to be destroyed.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update in php at authentication step in login page

```
if(email verified && password correctly entered){
    // add user related info to session
    $_SESSION['userInfo'] = ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Anunay']; //info can be retried from db
    session_start();
    //add redirect code to home.php or dashboard
}
```

in all files, top of the page you need to add `session_start()`

now you can add check in header portion

```
if(isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION)){
    //get id from session
    //get name from session 
    //you can add text welcome Anunay etc
}
```

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION)){` is redundant - all you need is `if (!empty($_SESSION)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to destroy the session when the user navigates to other page?

Instead passing the user ID through URL's query parameter, you can store the user ID in session.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id_from_wherever;
```

This will remain stored in the session until the session is destroyed or expired. You can use this to authenticate your user in the next page. Make sure to use `session_start();` before using session.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

When the user is successfully authenticated, define a value in $_SESSION, something like

```
$_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
```

Then, for each operation check if the value is defined and if it is not, redirect the user to the login page:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) &&  $_SESSION['authenticated']) {
  // do some stuff
} else {
  // redirect to the login page
}
```

Usually, in the $_SESSION you will store the user id, but since you want to be able to switch between users using the $_GET value, you can store just a boolean value, to know if a user is authenticated or not.

For the other thing (disable the back button) it is a bit difficult and it is not best practice to do that. I can think about 2 ways of doing that:

- Use an iframe for the entire page. All the navigation will be done inside the iframe and the back button will just go back to the previous script, before yours;
- Do all of your operations with AJAX. No reloads will be done for the entire page, just for fragments of code;

Of course, there are a lot of workarounds for doing that, more or less depending on the script logic.

Comment: I actually don't want to switch between users using the get

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need som identifier in your session that tells you which user is logged in - typically this would be the user ID (which is the primary key in your case). I am going to assume that this is the case, and that you have set it in such a manner as shown below, where `$row['userID']` is the result from the database after authenticating.

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];
```

Let's take your example of using `?id=4`, which you can get by using `$_GET['id']`. Then all you need to do is compare the two and see what the result is in your `dashboard.php`.

```php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    // User is not logged in at all, send 401 header (or you can do something entirely else)
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
    exit;
} elseif ($_SESSION['userID'] != $_GET['id']) {
    // User entered someone else's dashboard - redirect to his own dashboard
    header("Location: ?id=".$_SESSION['userID']);
    exit;
}
// If we're past these statements, the user is logged in and accessing his own dashboard
```

However, you can probably drop the `?id=4` part, and just use `$_SESSION['userID']` (or whatever you defined it as) instead to fetch the user-data, thus simply loading the current user's dashboard when you visit `/dashboard`.

Comment: What if there are multiple pages? Like I need to maintain the session on other pages too. $_SESSION works only for the next immediate page.

Comment: No, the session lasts until unset or destroyed - it is not just for the next page.

Comment: Will $_SESSION['id']; return result on every page? for example on all my pages if I write echo $_SESSION['id'], will it return a result?

Comment: If it exists, yes and as mentionned by @Qirel if you destroy the whole session or that specific variable and try to echo it once again it'll be gone.

Comment: I don't think so. Because it return an error: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in ______________ and the same code works on first page and when I use $_GET['id'], it works because it takes the i from URL

Comment: Then you're destroying or unsetting the session at some point. Sessions lasts for an entire session, not just until the next page load.